# Print all root to leaf path using recursion

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to print all root to leaf path using recursion, but I'm clueless
I don't know how to approach it, I'm completely stuck

```
<node id="N1">
    <node id="N1">
        <node id="N1"></node>
        <node id="N2"></node>
        <node id="N3"></node>
    </node>
</node>
```

desired output :

```
N1 N1 N1
N1 N1 N2
N1 N1 N3
```

Comment: Why recursion? `//node[not(*)]!string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@id, ' ')`

Comment: I thought recursion was the only way to do it, what does node[not(*)]! mean ?

Comment: `//node[not(*)]` selects the leaf `node` elements.  The `!` is the XPath 3 map operator, use `/` if you are restricted to 2.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to experiment with your code but I can't seem to add line break to achieve the desired output, is it not possible ?

Comment: Nevermind, I did it thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple

```
<xsl:value-of select="//node[not(*)]/string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@id, ' ')" separator="&#10;"/>
```

should do, without any need for recursion.